# How to validate the Empty Space in Path Params of REST URI

Tags: java, rest

My REST URI is :

GET commerce/customer/{id}/product-order/{product-order-id}/product-order-items

example 1 :

/commerce/customer/99999999/product-order/123/product-order-items

example 2:

/commerce/customer/99999999/product-order/  /product-order-items

```
@Path("/commerce/customer/{customer-id}/product-order/{product-order-id}/product-order-items")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public interface Something {

    @GET
    Response getSomething(
            @Context UriInfo uriInfo,
            @PathParam("customer-id") String customerId,
            @PathParam("product-order-id") String productOrderId,
            @QueryParam("sc") String salesChannel,
            @QueryParam("lo") String locale);
}
```

How can i do validation on product-order-id Path Param for spaces.

Comment: Instead of space why do you not use 0?

Comment: What does the URL `/product-order/product-order-items` actually mean? What is it expected to return?

Comment: I am just wondering what if person sends empty spaces in URI... My URI Matcher is : commerce/customer/.*/product-order/.*/product-order-items and  with no spaces : /product-order//product-order-items  or    with out productorderid  /product-order/product-order-items    URI wont hit my Interface